# Rails 4 : undefined local variable or method 'asset_paths' inside OldImagePath module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

I migrated my Rails 3.2.13 application to Rails 4.0, by creating a fresh new Rails 4 application and migrating the app/config/lib/db/routes/Gemfile/public into it. Everything seems to be working ok except for the following error:

Whenever I call `image_tag` ex. `<%= image_tag('home_vertical_separator.gif', :alt => 'Separator Image') %>`.

An error prompts:

`undefined local variable or method 'asset_paths' for #<#<Class:0x007fd5cb989b28>:0x007fd5cbdd2fe0>`

Inside `config/initializers/images_pipeline_path.rb` at the line `asset_paths.compute_public_path(source, 'images')`.

I know that sprockets is now considered as a separate project that is why I added the following line to the Gemfile:

`gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'`

Unfortunately it is still not working, any hints?

Comment: What is this `images_pipeline_path.rb`, where did you get that?

Comment: At first I thought it was from rails generator itself. Then I tried to create new application and it wasn't there. It must have been moved during the migration. It seems it was added during the migration from rails 3.0 and 3.1. Anyway it worked after removing the file! Thanks!

Comment: can you create an answer and then mark that as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed `images_pipeline_path.rb` file from my configuration and it worked.